# Go Kafka `ProduceChannel()` Fills Up and Hangs

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I have a server-side app written in Go producing Kafka events. It runs perfectly for days, producing ~1.6k msg/sec, and then hits a sporadic problem, where all Kafka message sending stops, and the server app needs to be manually restarted for Kafka messages to resume sending.

I've included a screenshot of the metric graphs when the incident started.  To annotate what I see happening:

- For seven days, the app runs perfectly. For every message queued, there is a delivery event notification sent to `kafkaProducer.Events()`. You can see that num queued = num delivered.
- 10:39: The issue starts. The delivery notification count quickly drops to zero. Kafka messages keep getting queued, but the callbacks stop.
- 10:52: `kafkaProducer.ProduceChannel()` is filled up, and attempts to queue new messsages into the go channel block the goroutine. At this point the app will never send another Kafka message again until it is manually restarted.
- 17:55: I manually restarted the application. kafka message queue/delivery resumes. kafka_produce_attempts drops back to zero.

The one and only place my Go code sends Kafka messages is here:

```
    recordChannelGauge.Inc()
    kafkaProducer.ProduceChannel() <- &msg
    recordChannelGauge.Dec()
```

In the metric screenshot, note that `recordChannelGauge` normally stays at zero because sending the message to the Kafka `ProduceChannel()` doesn't block and each `Inc()` is immediately followed by a matching `Dec()` However, when the `ProduceChannel()` is filled up, the goroutine blocks and `recordChannelGauge` stays at 1 and will never unblock until the app is manually restarted.

FYI, my environment details:

- Go server binary built with golang 1.10.x
- Latest version of `github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka`. This library doesn't use versions, it's using the latest git commit, which as of this writing is 2 months old, so I'm sure I'm using that latest version.
- Server OS Ubuntu 16.04.5
- librdkafka1 version librdka0.11.6~1confluent5.0.1-

I suspect this is due to some internal problem in the confluentinc go client, where it doesn't handle some error scenario appropriately.

Also, I see no relevant log output around the time of the problem. I do see sporadic Kafka broker disconnected and time out errors in the logs before the problem happened that don't seem to be serious. These log messages happened every few hours or so for days without serious consequence.

```
Nov 26 06:52:04 01 appserver.linux[6550]: %4|1543215124.447|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-broker-3:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-broker-3:9092/bootstrap: Timed out 0 in-flight, 1 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
Nov 26 06:52:10 01 appserver.linux[6550]: %4|1543215130.448|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-broker-3:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-broker-3:9092/bootstrap: Timed out 0 in-flight, 1 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
Nov 26 08:46:57 01 appserver.linux[6550]: 2018/11/26 08:46:57 Ignored event: kafka-broker-2:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected (after 600000ms in state UP)
Nov 26 08:47:02 01 appserver.linux[6550]: %4|1543222022.803|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-broker-2:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-broker-2:9092/bootstrap: Timed out 0 in-flight, 1 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
Nov 26 08:47:09 01 appserver.linux[6550]: %4|1543222029.807|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka-broker-2:9092/bootstrap]: kafka-broker-2:9092/bootstrap: Timed out 0 in-flight, 1 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
```

### Zoomed in to problem occurrence

[image: Zoomed in to problem occurrence]

### Zoomed out to show before and after

[image: Zoomed out to show before and after]

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem as you.And I found an article that might explain the cause of the problem.

**When there is no message in the blocked topic, after a certain period of time, you will timeout error as below.**

```
%5|1598190018.518|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://abcd....confluent.cloud:xxxx/2]: sasl_ssl://abcd....confluent.cloud:xxxx/2: Timed out FetchRequest in flight (after 359947ms, timeout #0)
%4|1598190018.840|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:sasl_ssl://abcd.confluent.cloud:xxxx/2]: sasl_ssl://abcd.xxxxx.confluent.cloud:xxxx/2: Timed out 1 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
```

The link of Article: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/apache-kafka-net-client-producer-consumer-csharp-confluent-examples-ii/

I hope that it can do some help to you.